# Will Hazelcast IMap block when waiting for an entry in transit?

Tags: hazelcast, distributed-system, hazelcast-imap

Assuming I have 2 nodes of Hazelcast that uses an `IMap` as cache.

If I have node1 store data into `IMap` with key K1 and value V1 while one millisecond later node2 attempts to get value from the same `IMap` with key K1, will node2 waits until K1 is synchronized to node2?

If node2 doesn't wait for K1, how to avoid node2 recreating V1 and put it in the `IMap` with key K1? I can't afford to have distributed lock as it will slowdown the entire system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no synchronization between nodes or recreating an entry to obtain it, for the data is stored in distributed form across the cluster. For example, when K1V1 is stored in IMap, it gets stored in one of the nodes and not replicated on all. When doing a imap.get(K1), the request goes to the owner member direct.

Comment: If that's the case, assuming K1V1 is stored in node1, how will node2 knows that K1V1 has been hold at node1? That information will have some latency to reach node2, right? What if before that information reach to node2, node2 does imap.get(K1)?

Comment: @Wins, members & client knows member list & partition table, when membership changed, meaning new members added or a member shutdown. After that, for all key-based operations, members & clients calculate the hashcode of the key, find the partition & partition owner of that key & send the request to that member directly.

Comment: @GokhanOner sure, however even during membership change, there is also repartition period. During those period the data is being moved, right? What if there is imap.get(K1) operation during that period?

Comment: @Wins, read operations retried automatically if failed, as described here:  https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#handling-failures. So you’ll get the data if it’s there, after migration completed, as response to your request, although it’ll be take a bit longer than usual, thats it.

Comment: @GokhanOner thanks for the insightful info. Can I summarize that each node will know in which kode a particular partition key is and when a node is asking for imap.get(K1) it will first calculate what the partition key is and find where the primary node for that partition key. Only then it will request remotely (if it happens to be located in remote node) the value for K1?

Comment: @Wins, correct. Also clients will do the same for key-based operations, not just members. You can find detailed info here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#how-the-data-is-partitioned

Comment: @GokhanOner thank you for the explanation. It really enlighten me confusion.